# can The solution of differential equation be converted to Fourier transformation always??

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, fourier-transform, greens-function

My question is just title. If that is true, How can I prove that?

Comment: Do you mean that the solution of a diff-eq can always be Fourier-transformed? if so: in what sense do you mean? i.e. as a function on $\mathbb{R}$, or $\mathbb{T}$ or even as a tempered distribution?